# How to create counter (IDENTITY) with THE OPTION TO GIVE SOME DIFFERENT lines the same Identity?

Tags: sql-server

For solving it I've created a table, which contains counters that activated by triggers.

I would like to make a better solution with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `IDENT_CURRENT(table_name)`. The tables structure
for ex:

```
first table:
A     B
1     34
2     12
3     78
4     90
5     23

second
C     D(-->A)
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     4
3     5

third:
E     F(-->C)
1     1
2     2
2     3
...
```

Comment: Sounds like poor design to me. Your identity column should always be unique. If you want some other column to allow duplicates then have a second column for that.

Comment: There are no duplications between lines (each line is different from the others). More columns=More memory used. What else can I do for updating the second&third tables in accordance with the A &C columns? (not FK pls)

Comment: In your question you said to "give some different lines the same identity" now you are saying you are not? One `int` column is not going to cause memory issues - if it solves the problem its the way to go. I don't understand the rest of your comment or for that matter really your question. Maybe you can clarify further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The PK in the second table is D (unique), and in third is F. I need to find a way to save the last ID for using it in other tables. The first table is the data from somewhere,  the A is the identity. the second D related to A and C is num of the classification. in the third table, F is related to C, and E is the classification F is related to.

Comment: I added an extra line to clarify the connection.